# Hibernate getting error in query when I put * anywhere in the query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a following query,

```
SELECT description, SUM( CASE WHEN entryType =  1 THEN amount ELSE amount * -1 END ) totals
FROM AccountDetails
GROUP BY account_id;
```

I got the result of above query in the `MySQL` terminal.
But when i try to do the same action in `Hibernate` query, with the following:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT description, SUM( CASE WHEN entryType =  1 THEN amount ELSE amount * -1 END ) totals FROM AcountDetails GROUP BY account_id;");
return query.list();
```

I got the following error,

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is 
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **expecting "end", found '*' near line 1, column 75** [SELECT description, SUM( CASE WHEN entryType =  1 THEN amount ELSE amount * -1 END ) totals FROM AcountDetails GROUP BY account_id;]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sql query`, instead of `hql query`. Also remove `;` from the end of the query.

It should be:

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT description, SUM( CASE WHEN entryType =  1 THEN amount ELSE amount * -1 END ) totals FROM AcountDetails GROUP BY account_id");
return query.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need to multiply, just use `-amount` instead of `amount * -1`